# A better way to reorganize dictionary key, value pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary

I begin with a simple python dictionary like this:-

```
In [29]: date_dict
Out[29]: 
{'2003-06-24': 2,
 '2003-08-13': 1,
 '2003-08-19': 2,
 '2003-08-22': 1,
 '2003-08-24': 5}
```

with the key being a date and the value an integer.

My goal is to reorganize the data in this dictionary into:-

```
{'datetime': ['2003-08-13',
  '2003-08-19',
  '2003-06-24',
  '2003-08-24',
  '2003-08-22'],
 'observations': [1, 2, 2, 5, 1]}
```

which maintains the data relationship between the list held by the `datetime` key and the list held by the `observations` key.

This is my solution to get this done:-

```
In [35]: new_dict
Out[35]: {'datetime': [], 'observations': []}

In [36]: for key, value in date_dict.iteritems():
   ....:     new_dict['datetime'].append(key)
   ....:     new_dict['observations'].append(value)

In [37]: new_dict
Out[37]: 
{'datetime': ['2003-08-13',
  '2003-08-19',
  '2003-06-24',
  '2003-08-24',
  '2003-08-22'],
 'observations': [1, 2, 2, 5, 1]}
```

My question is - are there alternative (better still, if more efficient) methods of doing this?

(Note that it is critical to maintain the data-relationship across the two lists, i.e. in the original date_dict, "2003-08-24" corresponds to value "5".  After the data is reorganized, the 3rd index of the 'datetime' list is "2003-08-24" which correctly corresponds to the 3rd index of the 'observations list' as "5".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe:

```
new_dict = {'datetime': date_dict.keys(), 'observations': date_dict.values()}
```

In case you need order try to use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of dict:

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict
>   methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys
>   were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the
>   original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and
>   reinserting it will move it to the end.

Comment: First thing I tried. This doesn't retain the data order and relationship.

Comment: @CalvinCheng -- What do you mean the data order and relationship?  `zip(d.keys(),d.values())` is functionally equivalent to `d.items()`

Comment: My bad... somehow I misread the output when I attempted your exact solution earlier. It works.

Comment: Nice mention about `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
dates, observations = zip(*date_dict.items())
```

Then pack up the `dates` and `observations` lists however you like.

You can sort with the same construct:

```
dates, observations = zip(*sorted(date_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a dictionary? I think a list of tuples does what you want better:

```
observations = [('2003-08-13',1),...]
```

Comment: I don't need dictionary per say. I just need to reorganize the data set into that format.